# Show button if cell is tapped and hide after leave in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

If someone taps over the cell or selects the cell then the button will show or else it'll be hidden. Only that cell that is playing the current song will show the button (it's for either play or stop) but the problem is the button shown on each row of the cell if didn't hide it also I don't want to hide the button if I click the playing song cell again.

```swift
class AudioListViewController: UIViewController {
    var selectedRowIndex = -1
    var songList: [Audio] = [
        Audio(id: 0, trackName: "Song 1", trackTitle: "ABbcd:", album: "Loreim loreim",
              uploadedBy: "A men", genre: "Romantic", lyricsLang: "English", artist: "God",
              duration: 2.00),
        Audio(id: 1, trackName: "Song 2", trackTitle: "ABbcd:", album: "Loreim loreim",
              uploadedBy: "A men", genre: "Romantic", lyricsLang: "English", artist: "God",
              duration: 2.00),
        Audio(id: 2, trackName: "Song 3", trackTitle: "ABbcd:", album: "Loreim loreim",
              uploadedBy: "A men", genre: "Romantic", lyricsLang: "English", artist: "God",
              duration: 2.00)
    ]
    @IBOutlet weak var songListTableView: UITableView!
    var isTapped: Bool = false
    @IBOutlet weak var close: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        songListTableView.dataSource = self
        songListTableView.delegate = self
        
        songListTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "SongsListTableViewCell", bundle: nil),
                                   forCellReuseIdentifier: "SongListCell")
    }
}

extension AudioListViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return songList.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SongListCell",
                                                 for: indexPath) as! SongsListTableViewCell
        
        cell.songTitle?.text = songList[indexPath.row].trackName
        cell.songDuration?.text = String(songList[indexPath.row].duration)
        return cell
    }
}

extension AudioListViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        let position = indexPath.row
        
        let vc = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SongListCell", 
                                               for: indexPath) as! SongsListTableViewCell
    }
}
```

My `UITableViewCell` code:

```swift
class SongsListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    public var position: Int = 0
    public var isPlaying: Bool = false
    var cellsState: Bool = false
    
    @IBOutlet weak var singleViewCell: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet weak var songCellView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var songImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var songTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var songDuration: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var makeFavorite: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var useSong: UIButton!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        useSong.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SongsListTableViewCell.selectSong(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        makeFavorite.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SongsListTableViewCell.makeFavourite(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        useSong.isHidden = true
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        useSong.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    }
    
    @IBAction func makeFavourite(_ sender: UIButton) {
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
        if sender.isSelected {
            makeFavorite.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "star.fill"), for: .normal)
        } else {
            makeFavorite.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "star"), for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

This is how it's looking right now:

[image: SongList view]

This is my Songlistview:

[image: songlistview]

Comment: The button should be part of your cell. You keep track of which item is playing and then use that when you configure the cell in `cellForRow`. When the current song changes or no song is playing simply reload the affected row(s)

Comment: @Paulw11 if I reload the row then the button will disappear which I don't want or is there anything else I can do to avoid the issue, really new to swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Tyler i am using function in UITableViewDelegate with didSelectRowAt and didDeselectRowAt to show and hide , and don't hide why i click the component in Cell , with the function will check row in the index path and call function hide/show

```
import UIKit

class ShowHideTableviewVC: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableview.dataSource = self
        self.tableview.delegate = self
    }
    
}

extension ShowHideTableviewVC: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        5
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ShowHideCell", for: indexPath) as! ShowHideCell
        return cell
    }
}

extension ShowHideTableviewVC: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ShowHideCell {
            cell.showButton(show: true)
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ShowHideCell {
            cell.showButton(show: false)
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the code in the cell it will hide the button component and make the height zero because we want hide the button component

```
import UIKit

class ShowHideCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonx: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var heightButton: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        showButton(show: false)
    }
    
    
    
    func showButton(show: Bool) {
        if show {
            heightButton.constant = 30
            buttonx.isHidden = !show
        } else {
            heightButton.constant = 0
            buttonx.isHidden = !show
        }
    }
}
```

it will not hide the button (play button) when you click the button component inner cell because it using selected in the UITableViewDelegate

Comment: Hi Hario your solution works but I got really simple solution
         `Class SongsListTableViewCell { override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) { if selected {    useSong.isHidden = false useSong.alpha = 1  } else {
   useSong.isHidden = true
    useSong.alpha = 0   } }`